# NodeJS parseInt() function does not return correct HEX value

Tags: node.js, math, binary, hex, parseint

I have the following code to convert a binary to a hex in NodeJS:

```
const bin = "1011100100001011101010100011100100001001101000100011101110110101101111011000001111111100010010111110001110101011100111101101110101100110110111000001111010101010110001110001110000110101001111111101000100110011111000010111110011001011000000001001010000100100"
const hex = parseInt(bin, 2).toString(16).toUpperCase();
console.log(hex)
```

and it only return:

```
B90BAA3909A23800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Im not sure, but this could be possible a "out of range" error. I think the number/input that `parseInt` returns is to big/long.With a smaler input, it works.

Comment: I looked a the source from "https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/binary-to-hex.html" they use the "BigNumber" pacakge on npm. `console.log((new BigNumber(bin, 2)).toString(16).toUpperCase())` Perhaps this works without "BigNumber" and instead of use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As maximum safe integer in JavaScript is just `2^53 - 1` or `0b11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` (see [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)), you need [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) here:

```js
const bigIntFromBin = BigInt("0b1011100100001011101010100011100100001001101000100011101110110101101111011000001111111100010010111110001110101011100111101101110101100110110111000001111010101010110001110001110000110101001111111101000100110011111000010111110011001011000000001001010000100100");
const bigIntHex = bigIntFromBin.toString(16).toUpperCase();
console.log(bigIntHex);
```